# add search button and text box in navigation control

Tags: ios, search, ios7, uinavigationcontroller

Can we add search button, search text box in to navigation control? Also, is it better to programmatically load view/view controller or use sague if you have complicated navigation?

Comment: Refer to the UISearchBar along with UISearchDisplayController. It is not complicated to integrate the search bar with UINavigationController